How to implement a mixture of gamma distributions in Python without Bayes'?
I am trying to create examples to compare and contrast Bayesian MCMC  (e.g. HMC) with non-Bayesian equivalents. One of the cases I am finding difficult is creating a mixture of gamma distributions.
I first had some provisional success with a mixture of two distributions:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma, rv_continuous
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

class gamma_mixture(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, w, a1, scale1, a2, scale2):
        return w * gamma.pdf(x, a1, scale=scale1) + (1 - w) * gamma.pdf(x, a2, scale=scale2)
    
    def fit(self, data):
        def log_likelihood(params):
            w, a1, scale1, a2, scale2 = params
            mixture = w * gamma.pdf(data, a1, scale=scale1) + (1 - w) * gamma.pdf(data, a2, scale=scale2)
            return -np.sum(np.log(mixture))

        initial_params = [0.8, 2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 1.0]
        bounds = [(0, 1), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None)]
        result = minimize(log_likelihood, initial_params, bounds=bounds, method='L-BFGS-B')
        if result.success:
            self.fitted_params = result.x
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Optimization failed")

# Generate sample data
np.random.seed(2018)
data = np.concatenate([
    gamma.rvs(a=2.0, scale=2.0, size=100),
    gamma.rvs(a=20.0, scale=1.0, size=100)
    ])

# Define and fit the gamma mixture model to the data
custom_gamma_mixture = gamma_mixture(name='gamma_mixture')
custom_gamma_mixture.fit(data)
w, a1, scale1, a2, scale2 = custom_gamma_mixture.fitted_params

# Evaluate the PDF of the fitted mixture model
x = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 1000)
pdf_vals = custom_gamma_mixture.pdf(x, w, a1, scale1, a2, scale2)

# Plot the fitted PDF against the histogram of the data
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
axes[0].hist(data, bins=30, density=True, alpha=0.6, color='g', label='Data Histogram')
axes[0].plot(x, pdf_vals, 'r-', lw=2, label='Fitted Mixture PDF')
axes[0].set_title('Original Sample')

axes[1].hist(custom_gamma_mixture(*custom_gamma_mixture.fitted_params).rvs(size=200), bins=30, density=True, alpha=0.6, color='b', label='Data Histogram')
axes[1].plot(x, pdf_vals, 'r-', lw=2, label='Fitted Mixture PDF')
axes[1].set_title('New Sample')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Output fitted parameters
print("Fitted Parameters:")
print(f"w: {w:.4f}")
print(f"a1: {a1:.4f}, scale1: {scale1:.4f}")
print(f"a2: {a2:.4f}, scale2: {scale2:.4f}")

I then tried to generalize to multiple distributions and found that either I got failures to converge or the plotted distribution just didn't look right. Here is an example:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from typing import Tuple

class GammaMixture:
    def __init__(self, n_components: int):
        self.n_components = n_components
        self.weights = np.ones(n_components) / n_components
        self.alphas = np.ones(n_components)
        self.scales = np.ones(n_components)

    def _pdf(self, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        mixture = np.sum(self.weights[i] * gamma.pdf(x, self.alphas[i], scale=self.scales[i]) for i in range(self.n_components))
        return mixture

    def _negative_log_likelihood(self, params: np.ndarray, data: np.ndarray) -> float:
        self.weights, self.alphas, self.scales = np.split(params, [self.n_components, 2*self.n_components])
        self.weights = np.exp(self.weights) / np.sum(np.exp(self.weights))  # Ensure probabilities sum to 1
        neg_log_likelihood = -np.sum(np.log(self._pdf(data)))
        return neg_log_likelihood

    def fit(self, data: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
        initial_params = np.concatenate([np.zeros(self.n_components), np.ones(2*self.n_components)])
        bounds = [(0, None)] * self.n_components + [(0, None)] * (2*self.n_components)
        result = minimize(self._negative_log_likelihood, initial_params, args=(data,), bounds=bounds)
        if result.success:
            self.weights, self.alphas, self.scales = np.split(result.x, [self.n_components, 2*self.n_components])
            self.weights = np.exp(self.weights) / np.sum(np.exp(self.weights))  # Ensure probabilities sum to 1
            return self.weights, self.alphas, self.scales
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Optimization failed")

    def sample(self, n_samples: int) -> np.ndarray:
        components = np.random.choice(self.n_components, size=n_samples, p=self.weights)
        samples = np.array([gamma.rvs(self.alphas[i], scale=self.scales[i]) for i in components])
        return samples

# Example usage:
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.concatenate([
    gamma.rvs(a=2.0, scale=2.0, size=100),
    gamma.rvs(a=20.0, scale=1.0, size=100)
])

n_components = 3
gamma_mixture = GammaMixture(n_components)
weights, alphas, scales = gamma_mixture.fit(data)

print("Fitted Parameters:")
print("Weights:", weights)
print("Alphas:", alphas)
print("Scales:", scales)

# Generate samples from the fitted model
samples = gamma_mixture.sample(n_samples=1000)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot histograms
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

# Histogram of original data
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.hist(data, bins=30, density=True, color='blue', alpha=0.6, label='Original Data')
plt.title('Histogram of Original Data')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.legend()

# Histogram of new samples
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.hist(samples, bins=30, density=True, color='orange', alpha=0.6, label='New Samples')
plt.title('Histogram of New Samples')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

I had wondered if maybe I should use expectation maximization, so I tried that also using KMeans clustering to give the process a warm start:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

class GammaMixture:
    def __init__(self, n_components: int):
        """
        Initialize the Gamma Mixture Model.

        Args:
            n_components (int): Number of gamma distributions (components) in the mixture.
        """
        self.n_components = n_components
        self.weights = np.ones(n_components) / n_components
        self.alphas = np.ones(n_components)
        self.scales = np.ones(n_components)
        self.fitted = False

    def _e_step(self, data: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        E-step: Calculate the responsibilities.

        Args:
            data (np.ndarray): Observed data.

        Returns:
            np.ndarray: Responsibilities of each component for each data point.
        """
        responsibilities = np.zeros((data.shape[0], self.n_components))
        for i in range(self.n_components):
            responsibilities[:, i] = self.weights[i] * gamma.pdf(data, a=self.alphas[i], scale=self.scales[i])
        
        sum_responsibilities = np.sum(responsibilities, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
        if np.any(sum_responsibilities == 0):
            raise ValueError("Some data points have zero responsibilities.")
        
        responsibilities /= sum_responsibilities
        return responsibilities

    def _m_step(self, data: np.ndarray, responsibilities: np.ndarray):
        """
        M-step: Update the parameters of the gamma distributions and the weights.

        Args:
            data (np.ndarray): Observed data.
            responsibilities (np.ndarray): Responsibilities of each component for each data point.
        """
        total_resp = np.sum(responsibilities, axis=0)
        self.weights = total_resp / data.shape[0]

        for i in range(self.n_components):
            resp = responsibilities[:, i]
            weighted_data_sum = np.sum(resp * data)
            weighted_log_data_sum = np.sum(resp * np.log(data))

            if total_resp[i] == 0 or weighted_data_sum == 0 or weighted_log_data_sum == 0:
                raise ValueError(f"Invalid weighted sums for component {i}: total_resp={total_resp[i]}, weighted_data_sum={weighted_data_sum}, weighted_log_data_sum={weighted_log_data_sum}")

            self.alphas[i] = total_resp[i] / (np.sum(resp * np.log(data)) - np.sum(resp) * np.log(weighted_data_sum / total_resp[i]))
            self.scales[i] = weighted_data_sum / (total_resp[i] * self.alphas[i])

            if np.isnan(self.alphas[i]) or np.isnan(self.scales[i]):
                raise ValueError(f"NaN encountered in alphas or scales during M-step for component {i}.")

            print(f"Component {i}: alpha={self.alphas[i]}, scale={self.scales[i]}, weight={self.weights[i]}")

    def _warm_start(self, data: np.ndarray):
        """
        Warm start the parameters using K-means clustering.

        Args:
            data (np.ndarray): Observed data.
        """
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=self.n_components, random_state=0)
        labels = kmeans.fit_predict(data.reshape(-1, 1))
        
        for i in range(self.n_components):
            cluster_data = data[labels == i]
            if len(cluster_data) == 0:
                continue
            data_mean = np.mean(cluster_data)
            data_var = np.var(cluster_data)
            self.alphas[i] = data_mean ** 2 / data_var
            self.scales[i] = data_var / data_mean
            self.weights[i] = len(cluster_data) / len(data)
            print(f"Warm start Component {i}: alpha={self.alphas[i]}, scale={self.scales[i]}, weight={self.weights[i]}")

    def fit(self, data: np.ndarray, tol: float = 1e-6, max_iter: int = 100):
        """
        Fit the Gamma Mixture Model to the data.

        Args:
            data (np.ndarray): Observed data.
            tol (float): Tolerance for convergence.
            max_iter (int): Maximum number of iterations.

        Raises:
            RuntimeError: If the optimization fails to converge.
        """
        self._warm_start(data)

        log_likelihood_prev = -np.inf
        for iteration in range(max_iter):
            responsibilities = self._e_step(data)
            self._m_step(data, responsibilities)

            log_likelihood = np.sum(np.log(np.sum([w * gamma.pdf(data, a, scale=s) for w, a, s in zip(self.weights, self.alphas, self.scales)], axis=0)))
            print(f"Iteration {iteration}: log_likelihood={log_likelihood}")

            if np.abs(log_likelihood - log_likelihood_prev) < tol:
                break
            log_likelihood_prev = log_likelihood

        if np.any(np.isnan(self.weights)) or np.any(np.isnan(self.alphas)) or np.any(np.isnan(self.scales)):
            raise ValueError("NaN encountered in parameters after fitting.")
        
        self.fitted = True

    def sample(self, n_samples: int) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Sample from the fitted Gamma Mixture Model.

        Args:
            n_samples (int): Number of samples to generate.

        Returns:
            np.ndarray: Samples generated from the model.

        Raises:
            RuntimeError: If the model has not been fitted yet.
        """
        if not self.fitted:
            raise RuntimeError("Model has not been fitted yet. Fit the model first.")

        samples = np.zeros(n_samples)
        component_samples = np.random.choice(self.n_components, size=n_samples, p=self.weights)

        for i in range(self.n_components):
            n_component_samples = np.sum(component_samples == i)
            if n_component_samples > 0:
                samples[component_samples == i] = gamma.rvs(a=self.alphas[i], scale=self.scales[i], size=n_component_samples)

        return samples

# Example usage
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.concatenate([
    gamma.rvs(a=2, scale=2, size=300),
    gamma.rvs(a=5, scale=1, size=300),
    gamma.rvs(a=9, scale=0.5, size=400)
])

gamma_mixture = GammaMixture(n_components=3)
gamma_mixture.fit(data)
samples = gamma_mixture.sample(n_samples=1000)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.histplot(data, color='blue', kde=True, label='Observed', stat='density')
sns.histplot(samples, color='red', kde=True, label='Sampled', stat='density')
plt.title('Distribution of Observed vs Sampled Data')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

But that also gave either convergence issues or visually poor agreement with the data. Lastly, I tried a warm start that used method of moments:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma

class GammaMixture:
    def __init__(self, n_components: int):
        """
        Initialize the Gamma Mixture Model.

        Args:
            n_components (int): Number of gamma distributions (components) in the mixture.
        """
        self.n_components = n_components
        self.weights = np.ones(n_components) / n_components
        self.alphas = np.ones(n_components)
        self.scales = np.ones(n_components)
        self.fitted = False

    def _e_step(self, data: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        E-step: Calculate the responsibilities.

        Args:
            data (np.ndarray): Observed data.

        Returns:
            np.ndarray: Responsibilities of each component for each data point.
        """
        responsibilities = np.zeros((data.shape[0], self.n_components))
        for i in range(self.n_components):
            responsibilities[:, i] = self.weights[i] * gamma.pdf(data, a=self.alphas[i], scale=self.scales[i])
        
        sum_responsibilities = np.sum(responsibilities, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
        if np.any(sum_responsibilities == 0):
            raise ValueError("Some data points have zero responsibilities.")
        
        responsibilities /= sum_responsibilities
        return responsibilities

    def _m_step(self, data: np.ndarray, responsibilities: np.ndarray):
        """
        M-step: Update the parameters of the gamma distributions and the weights.

        Args:
            data (np.ndarray): Observed data.
            responsibilities (np.ndarray): Responsibilities of each component for each data point.
        """
        total_resp = np.sum(responsibilities, axis=0)
        self.weights = total_resp / data.shape[0]

        for i in range(self.n_components):
            resp = responsibilities[:, i]
            weighted_data_sum = np.sum(resp * data)
            weighted_log_data_sum = np.sum(resp * np.log(data))

            if total_resp[i] == 0 or weighted_data_sum == 0 or weighted_log_data_sum == 0:
                raise ValueError(f"Invalid weighted sums for component {i}: total_resp={total_resp[i]}, weighted_data_sum={weighted_data_sum}, weighted_log_data_sum={weighted_log_data_sum}")

            self.alphas[i] = (total_resp[i] / weighted_log_data_sum)
            self.scales[i] = (weighted_data_sum / total_resp[i]) / self.alphas[i]

            if np.isnan(self.alphas[i]) or np.isnan(self.scales[i]):
                raise ValueError(f"NaN encountered in alphas or scales during M-step for component {i}.")
            print(f"Component {i}: alpha={self.alphas[i]}, scale={self.scales[i]}, weight={self.weights[i]}")

    def _warm_start(self, data: np.ndarray):
        """
        Warm start the parameters using Method of Moments.

        Args:
            data (np.ndarray): Observed data.
        """
        data_mean = np.mean(data)
        data_var = np.var(data)
        
        for i in range(self.n_components):
            self.alphas[i] = data_mean ** 2 / data_var
            self.scales[i] = data_var / data_mean
            self.weights[i] = 1 / self.n_components
            print(f"Warm start Component {i}: alpha={self.alphas[i]}, scale={self.scales[i]}, weight={self.weights[i]}")

    def fit(self, data: np.ndarray, tol: float = 1e-6, max_iter: int = 100):
        """
        Fit the Gamma Mixture Model to the data.

        Args:
            data (np.ndarray): Observed data.
            tol (float): Tolerance for convergence.
            max_iter (int): Maximum number of iterations.

        Raises:
            RuntimeError: If the optimization fails to converge.
        """
        self._warm_start(data)

        log_likelihood_prev = -np.inf
        for iteration in range(max_iter):
            responsibilities = self._e_step(data)
            self._m_step(data, responsibilities)

            log_likelihood = np.sum(np.log(np.sum([w * gamma.pdf(data, a, scale=s) for w, a, s in zip(self.weights, self.alphas, self.scales)], axis=0)))
            print(f"Iteration {iteration}: log_likelihood={log_likelihood}")

            if np.abs(log_likelihood - log_likelihood_prev) < tol:
                break
            log_likelihood_prev = log_likelihood

        if np.any(np.isnan(self.weights)) or np.any(np.isnan(self.alphas)) or np.any(np.isnan(self.scales)):
            raise ValueError("NaN encountered in parameters after fitting.")
        
        self.fitted = True

    def sample(self, n_samples: int) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Sample from the fitted Gamma Mixture Model.

        Args:
            n_samples (int): Number of samples to generate.

        Returns:
            np.ndarray: Samples generated from the model.

        Raises:
            RuntimeError: If the model has not been fitted yet.
        """
        if not self.fitted:
            raise RuntimeError("Model has not been fitted yet. Fit the model first.")

        samples = np.zeros(n_samples)
        component_samples = np.random.choice(self.n_components, size=n_samples, p=self.weights)

        for i in range(self.n_components):
            n_component_samples = np.sum(component_samples == i)
            if n_component_samples > 0:
                samples[component_samples == i] = gamma.rvs(a=self.alphas[i], scale=self.scales[i], size=n_component_samples)

        return samples

# Example usage
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.concatenate([
    gamma.rvs(a=2, scale=2, size=300),
    gamma.rvs(a=5, scale=1, size=300),
    gamma.rvs(a=9, scale=0.5, size=400)
])

gamma_mixture = GammaMixture(n_components=3)
gamma_mixture.fit(data)
samples = gamma_mixture.sample(n_samples=1000)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.histplot(data, color='blue', kde=True, label='Observed', stat='density')
sns.histplot(samples, color='red', kde=True, label='Sampled', stat='density')
plt.title('Distribution of Observed vs Sampled Data')
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

How should I actually go about implementing a mixture of gamma distributions without using Bayes'?


Wikipedia suggests heuristics like simulated annealing to improve the behaviour of EM algorithm. Perhaps the same could be said for MLE.
Something I have not explored yet is the numerical stability of objective function. Perhaps computing the pdfs and then taking their logarithms is worse than some other approach. Unfortunately logarithms will not distribute over a sum, the log of the likelihood of a mixture distribution might not be better. I don't know if this would be an improvement, but I could look at computing Taylor series expansions of the log likelood instead.

